# Why do I need to remove one AirPod from its case twice for it to connect?

Tags: airpods

My AirPods (2nd gen A2031) have often stopped connecting both ears to my phone or other devices when first removed from their case.

The left AirPod often doesn’t connect until I put it back in the case and remove it again. This solves the problem every time. What causes this?

I have cleaned them with a cocktail stick, cotton buds with alcohol and compressed air, but none of this has improved it. The battery life on both AirPods is still good.

Comment: What AirPods model do you have?

Comment: Have you tried what's described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207974)?

Comment: @Thinkr - I have added the model number to the question - A2031.  I have re-connected them using those steps.  When I do that, both AirPods connect for a few days, then the unreliability of one side creeps in over time.

Comment: This is symptomatic of a failing component.  Think of it as synonymous as flipping a light switch several times to get it to turn on.  In this case, there’s no software or setting you can mofify to fix this, so it will have to be replaced